# Check for empty href atribute in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an idea I'd like to implement to a site I'm working on.  I've got an idea of how it would work but I'm not entirely sure how to piece the bits together.

So!!  I'd like to check the domain and generate an alert box if it's necessary to do so.

Say we have 2 domains:

```
test.domain.com & domain.com
```

IF we're on **test.domain.com** and there's no content inside the href *(Missing Link)*, I'd like an alert box to pop up saying "MISSING LINK".  And if there is content inside the href, just ignore it *(Not Missing Link)*.

```
<a href="">Missing Link</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Not Missing Link</a>
```

Then, if we were on **domain.com** I'd like the jQuery to still be present in the code, but it to do nothing if a **Missing Link** was clicked.  As it will just redirect to the home page - Not the best journey, but much better than an intrusive popup box.

This way I could use a tiny bit of code to check missing links at the test stage, but not have to remove it every time it gets sent to the actual domain.

If any of this doesn't make sense, please ask!

Thanks a million, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", 'a[href=""]', function(evt) {
    if(window.location.hostname.indexOf("test")!==-1) {
        alert("broken");
    } else {
        window.location.href = "foo.html";
    }
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Personally if I were making a page on test to determine if a link is broken, I would do something so they would stand out when the page is open. Instead of clicking to find out.

```
if(window.location.hostname.indexOf("test")!==-1) {
    $('a[href=""]').css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help with this - After the popup the link still takes you to the homepage as it would without the popup.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Not sure why it would take you to the homepage..., but add evt.preventDeafult(); updated answer

Comment: yo, good answer combine with mine - put `e.preventDefault(); ` above `alert('broken'); `

Comment: Fantastic!  Appreciate both of your inputs!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to get you started. It feels to me as though whatever it is you’re trying, we’re taking completely the wrong approach.

```
if (location.host === 'test.domain.com' && !$('a[href=""]').length) {
  alert('MISSING LINK');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hows this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    var a = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    if($.trim(a.prop('href')) == "")
    {
        alert("No link")
    }
    else   
    {
        window.location = $.trim(a.prop('href'));
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: really? worked for me.. cant do a jsfiddle cos it'll resolve the empty href to be something that its not :( -  i made a quick edit try that..

Comment: also - if your running that code and its not working can you try `console.log ` the `$.trim(a.prop('href') ` part and make sure its not coming back with undefined.. in which case though it should have brought you somewhere.